# For next sub returning same value down the colum in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm brand new to VBA and am trying to understand how to add/change my code, so that the value in each cell changes as the code calculates down the 2 columns of data I have. Right now, I have the same value going down 13000 rows. This is my code:

```
Sub SReturn()
    For Index = 1 To 13000
        If Range("H3").Cells(Index, 1) = Range("H2").Cells(Index, 1) Then
        Range("I3").Cells(Index, 1) = Log(Range("F3") / Range("F2"))
    Else: Range("I3").Cells(Index, 1) = " "
        End If
    Next Index
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you want the value to change?

Comment: So I have a list of prices that I'm calculating returns from in column F. I want to take the ln(F3/F2), which I have now, and then I want the next cell down to calculate ln(F4/F3), then ln((F5/F4), and so on if that makes more sense.

Comment: `Range("H3:H13000").Formula = "=LN(F3/F2)"`, though you may want to look into finding the last row in order not to populate formulas where they are not needed

Comment: bad use of `" "`. Use `vbNullString` instead

Comment: Also you want to `R1C1` formula style. This way the formula will reference the correct cell/s